# Anyone have experience with PHP and Fannie Mae File Formats (or MISMO)?

Tags: php, standards

I'm working on a mortgage application and we're supposed to use the FNM 3.2 file format but I can't find much in the way of applicable resources.

Hoping someone in the community has some experience.

Comment: http://lmhelp.leads360.com/entries/156982-fannie-mae-3-2-fm3-2-fanniemae-file-format there is a link that might help those looking for an answer. I'm still in the dark about this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get help from
https://documents.efanniemae.com/sf/technology/support/integration/integguide/data/

format of .fnm file should like

`Field Number/Offset/Requirement:Field Description:Value`

e.g

```
Line [1    ] Record ID - Envelope Header                      :EH 
EH-020 /  4/N  :Institution ID                                :
EH-030 / 10/N  :Institution Name                              :
EH-040 / 35/N  :Date                                          :20131118
EH-050 / 46/Y  :Envelope Control Number                       :18:16:39
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I am having a similar issue.  I heard you have to register with eFannieMae.com to be allowed access to the schema, but I have not found any more information regarding how to sign up or where to access the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the specification that you want
https://www.fanniemae.com/content/technology_requirements/residential-loan-data-1003-integration-guide.xlsx

The tab labeled "RLD 1003 3.2 Table" (5th one) has the fields specified.

Each line in the FNM file is a "section" on this spreadsheet (denoted by gray background row with merged cells).

- The first section (spreadsheet rows 3-7) refers to line 1 on the FNM file.
- The 2nd section (spreadsheet rows 9 to 19) refers to line 2 on the FNM file.
- and so on ...